# aws cognito swift header error

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to use aws cognito with swift, by installing it using pod. However after i've pod installed:

```
pod 'AWSCognito'
pod 'AWSCore'
```

i keep getting following errors `could not build Objective-C module 'AWSCore'` on

```
import AWSCore
import AWSCognito
```

and inside the aws cognito pod i get following error `include of non-modular header inside framework module 'AWSCore'` on

```
 #import <sqlite3.h>
```

i've tried setting non-moduler headers to yes and deleted derrived data, but it still can't build?

Comment: How did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You should create the bridging header file to use Objective c code in swift. To create the bridging header file click **file -> New -> File -> iOS -> header file**. Then name your bridging header file as following pattern “YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”. Then add following in your header file to access objective c frameworks.

```
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
#import <AWSCognito/AWSCognito.h>
```

Then configure your “YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h” in build setting,

Select your project target -> Build settings -> Swift compiler - general -> Objective c bridging header -> Add your bridging header file with complete path.(Or Simply do click **option-key + drag**)